# Can I view and cancel my pending edits?

Tags: support, editing

I am still relatively new to this site, so I am wondering if it is possible for me to view my pending edits? If so, can I also cancel them? Whenever I try to look at pending edits I am told that my reputation is not high enough to take any action on pending edits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can view them in your profile: https://askubuntu.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions (which should redirect to https://askubuntu.com/users/1082980/sleipnir?tab=activity&sort=suggestions for you).

As for cancelling, [not currently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80933/270345).